# Infinite loop and memory overflow in file handling C++

Tags: windows, atl

This piece of code below crashes, or ends up in an endless loop depending on how big the input file is. I think the A2T line is causing the overflow but I'm not sure what to use instead. I will appreciate any help in making my code concise and secure.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

```
#define END "\r\n"
#define TAG "Is this string in this line"
std::fstream myFile;
std::fstream outFile;
char cLine[300];
while (!myFile.eof() && !myFile.fail())
{
    tstring tTemp = A2T(cLine);
    if ( tstring::npos == tTemp.find(TAG))
    {
        outFile.write(cLine, strnlen(cLine, 300));
        if (!outFile.bad())
        {
            outFile.write(END, strnlen(END, 300));
        }

        if (outFile.bad())
        {
           break;
        }
    }
    myFile.getline(cLine, 300);
}
```

Comment: You are accessing `cLine` before it was initialized. Listen to your compiler's warnings. On a second thought, this is not the code that's exposing the problem you're describing. Please post the **real** code.

Comment: This is the real code

Comment: Uhm... I don't see `myFile` or `outFile` being opened. Neither do I see the code compile once you `#define _UNICODE`, so the `A2T` is kind of meaningless, essentially a no-op.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I open the files before the while loop, and close them after. it compiles and opens, and writes into the files -- no problem.

Comment: So again... please post the **real** code.

Comment: What do people have against `while ( myFile.getline( sizeof(cLine) ) )`?  (Of course, `std::string line; while ( std::getline( myFile, line )` would be a lot better.)

Comment: "A2T" uses "alloca()" - so you are allocating the entire contents of the input file on the stack. A large file will blow your stack.
Instead of using "tstring" and incurring tons of allocation overhead, just use a function like "strstr()" to search cLinep[] directly - no need to make a couple of copies of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A2T" uses "alloca()" - so you are allocating the entire contents of the input file on the stack. A large file will blow your stack. Instead of using "tstring" and incurring tons of allocation overhead, just use a function like "strstr()" to search cLinep[] directly - no need to make a couple of copies of it.

EDIT: As IInspectable pointed out, this code seems to be being compiled as ANSI, so "T" is "char" and A2T is no-op. That is, unless the real code shows something we aren't seeing here. Either way, there is no need to convert to string just to search for TAG, so this code below still is better.

```
#define END "\r\n"
#define TAG "Is this string in this line"
std::fstream myFile;
std::fstream outFile;
char cLine[300] = {0}; // Make sure this is initialized

while (!myFile.eof() && !myFile.fail())
{
    char *p = strstr(c, TAG);
    if (p == 0)  // Exclude lines with "TAG" in them.
    {
        outFile.write(cLine, strnlen(cLine, 300));
        if (!outFile.bad())
        {
            outFile.write(END, strnlen(END, 300));
        }

        if (outFile.bad())
        {
           break;
        }
    }
    myFile.getline(cLine, 300);
}
```

Comment: `A2T` as used in the example is a no-op. The code only compiles if `_UNICODE` is not defined. In other words, `TCHAR` is a `char`. In this scenario, `A2T` simply returns the pointer passed to it.